# file.replace('abcd') also replaces 'abcde' How do I only replace exact value?

Tags: python, linux, replace

```
def censor2(filename):
    infile = open(filename,'r')
    contents = infile.read()
    contentlist = contents.split()
    print (contents)
    print (contentlist)
    for letter in contentlist:
        if len(letter) == 4:
            print (letter)
            contents = contents.replace(letter,'xxxx')
    outfile = open('censor.txt','w')
    outfile.write(contents)
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

This code works in Python. It accepts a file 'example.txt', reads it and loops through replacing all 4 letter words with the string 'xxxx' and outputting this into a new file (keeping original format!) called censored.txt.

I used the replace function and find the words to be replaced. However, the word 'abcd' is replaced and the next word 'abcde' is turned into 'xxxxe'

How do i prevent 'abcde' from being changed?

I could not get the below examples to work, but after working with the re.sub module i found that the following code works to replace only 4 letter words and not 5 letter words.

```
contents = re.sub(r"(\b)\w{4}(\b)", r"\1xxxxx\2", contents)
```

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
re.sub(r'\babcd\b','',my_text)
```

this will require it to have word boundaries on either side

Comment: This answer is getting downvoted, but he just forgot the `r` in front of the string literal.  It's a simple typo/mistake, and anyone can easily edit the answer to correct it.  This highlights the weird tension in the Stackexchange model between wiki-style collaborative/community editing and reputation-based personal competition.

Comment: @CharlesSalvia This is goofiest thing ( downvotes) I've seen on SO this week.  Perhaps the other problem is that downvotes don't have enough of a penalty?

Comment: @David, it's a tough problem - because if downvotes had too much of a penalty nobody would ever downvote, and then crappy answers wouldn't be penalized.  I don't know what the optimal solution is here - but I definitely think that the wiki-style collaborative/community editing aspect of SO is the most neglected feature.

Answer (score 1):

This is where regular expressions can be helpful. You would want something like this:

```
import re
...
contents = re.sub(r'\babcd\b', 'xxxx', contents)
....
```

The `\b` is the "word boundary" marker. It matches the change from a word to whitespace characters, punctuation, etc.

You'll need the `r''` style string for the regex pattern so that the backslashes are not treated as escape characters.